# Is it possible to configure the size of top level in Sunburst chart similar to the innerSize in Pie chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

Highcharts provides a property "innerSize" to configure the size of the inner diameter for the pie. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/pie-innersize-80px/

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        innerSize: 80
    }
},
```

I tried to configure the size of topmost level in the Sunburst chart, by setting the size property in levels array, for level: 1. JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amrutaJgtp/tk4kprhc/4/

```
levels: [{
    level:1,
  size:500
},{
  level: 2,
  colorByPoint: true,
  dataLabels: {
    rotationMode: 'parallel'
  }
}, {
  level: 3,
  colorVariation: {
    key: 'brightness',
    to: -0.5
  }
}, {
  level: 4,
  colorVariation: {
    key: 'brightness',
    to: 0.5
  }
}]
```

I had checked in the API reference that Highcharts doesnt provide size property in levels. However, I would like to configure the size of level 1 only, so as to vary the size of innermost circle in the sunburst chart. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly this code works:

```
  plotOptions: {
    sunburst: {
      innerSize: 100
    }
  }
```

although it's not documented.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/5x3vzs8f/

Comment: I have already tried this way. In your example, i didnt want the ring for World level to appear.. I would like to configure the diameter of "World" level itself, not its inner size.

Comment: Yes, your're right. Sorry for this misunderstanding. I didn't find any way to make this work using options - Highcharts doesn't seem to provide that kind of functionality. Have you tried to use this **modified donut** chart?:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-donut/

It looks similar to sunburst.

Comment: Its okay.. Yes i have tried the modified donut chart too. I know there its possible to control the size since there are seperate series. However I want to achieve the same for Sunburst chart.